# .htaccess Rewrite rules for stopping executing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Most of my htaccess rules redirects unsigned users to `index.html`.
But when I redirect them to `index.html`, all of these rules are re-run for that page also. I need to run a minimum set of rules for the users visiting index file.

It's obvious that `[L]` stops htaccess rules' running.

What would be the better way for this issue? Is this a proper way to do it or do you have any better recommendations?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]
```

My full htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\/onefolder|\/secondfolder) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !111\.22\.33\.44 [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index\.html) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [F]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} oneagent|otheragent [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index\.html) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html? [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} betteragent|otherbetterganet [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index\.html) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html? [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !username [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/importantone|\/somefolder|index\.html) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things you can do. If you want to simply stop rewriting for `index.html`, you can do something similar to what you have (but simpler), at the very top of your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/?index.html$ - [L]
```

The `-` is simply to "pass through", essentially making it so rewriting stops there.

Alternatively, you can prevent looping completely by adding this to the top of your rules:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Does something similar but checks if there was an internal redirect of any kind.